# Replacing an element in ICollection

Tags: c#, .net, collections, icollection

Suppose I have an `ICollection<SomeClass>`.

I have the following two variables:

```
SomeClass old;
SomeClass new;
```

How can I achieve something like the following using an `ICollection<SomeClass>`?

```
// old is guaranteed to be inside collection
collection.Replace(old, new);
```

Comment: What implementation of `ICollection<T>` are you using?

Comment: @Valentin I'm talking about doing it using `ICollection` interface

Comment: It depends what type is implement this interface.

Comment: @stuartd Should it matter? I'm using `HashSet<SomeClass>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no black magic here: `ICollection<T>` is not ordered and only provides `Add`/`Remove` methods. Your only solution would be to check if the actual implementation is something *more*, such as `IList<T>`:

```
public static void Swap<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, T oldValue, T newValue)
{
    // In case the collection is ordered, we'll be able to preserve the order
    var collectionAsList = collection as IList<T>;
    if (collectionAsList != null)
    {
        var oldIndex = collectionAsList.IndexOf(oldValue);
        collectionAsList.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
        collectionAsList.Insert(oldIndex, newValue);
    }
    else
    {
        // No luck, so just remove then add
        collection.Remove(oldValue);
        collection.Add(newValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: this really helped me for removing items from a collection using index

Answer (score 0):

The [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx) interface is quite limited, you will have to use `Remove()` and `Add()`

```
collection.Remove(old);
collection.Add(new);
```

Comment: I thought about this, but `new` will be added to the end of the collection, instead of `old`'s location

Comment: Ya, that's why I removed my comment. But it would be more accurate to say `ICollection` is not guaranteed to have an order. For that you should be using something more specific that is common between all of your used collection types that actually supports order. Perhaps `IList<T>` instead?

Comment: @MatiasCicero, Even thought it has some order, it is only implementation detail and you shouldn't refer to it when you design your classes.

Comment: @MatiasCicero If you need an ordered collection, you should use `IList<T>`

Comment: @MatiasCicero You mentioned that you use `HashSet<T>` as the `ICollection<T>` implementation. Sets are by definition unordered. From MSDN HashSet doc: "A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order."

Comment: not always work, ie if you remove inside a foreach statement

Answer (score -1):

Do that:

```
    yourCollection.ToList()[index] = newValue;
```

Comment: Although this answer may help OP, consider to improve your answer by providing steps taken in to solve problem